How to allow one authentication flow to upload to a few YT channels?
We have to create the refresh token with the owner account only. Right?
But then how do we upload to a few YT channels?
Is there a conflict between auth/upload APIs?

YouTube Data API does not currently support the Studio Permissions model for authentication

But

onBehalfOfContentOwner and onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel parameters are intended for exclusively for YouTube content partners (Studio Permissions right?)

